# parse nested maps (hashMap) in gsp

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

it's all in the title.
I've been trying to parse nested Maps built as shown below in my example controller:

```
    def index() {

    Map<String, Object> motherMap = new HashMap<String, Object>()
    Map<String, String> childMap1 = new HashMap<String, String>()
    Map<String, String> childMap2 = new HashMap<String, String>()
    Map<String, String> childMap3 = new HashMap<String, String>()

    childMap1.put("cm1_key1", "cm1_value1")
    childMap1.put("cm1_key2", "cm1_value2")
    childMap1.put("cm1_key3", "cm1_value3")

    childMap2.put("cm2_key1", "cm2_value1")
    childMap2.put("cm2_key2", "cm2_value2")
    childMap2.put("cm2_key3", "cm2_value3")

    childMap3.put("cm3_key1", "cm3_value1")
    childMap3.put("cm3_key2", "cm3_value2")
    childMap3.put("cm3_key3", "cm3_value3")

    motherMap.put("mm_key1", childMap1)
    motherMap.put("mm_key2", childMap2)
    motherMap.put("mm_key3", childMap3)

    render (view: "thePage", model:[motherMap: motherMap])
}
```

in the GSP i try to get childMaps elements like this:

```
    ... html / gsp code ...
    <table>
        <g:each in="${motherMap.entrySet()}" var="entry">
            <g:if test="${entry.key != 'mm_key2'}">
                <g:each in="${entry.value.entrySet()}" var="childMap">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${childMap.key}</td>
                        <td>${childMap.value}</td>
                    </tr>
                </g:each>
            </g:if>
        </g:each>
    </table>
    ... html / gsp code ...
```

but i got an exeption when processing the page. The `entry.value` is interpreted as a String so the call to `.entrySet()` causes the exception.

Is there a way to get the content of child maps with GSP tags ?

edit:

@Sérgio Michels:
I'm using Grails 1.3.7 with Groovy 1.7 (imposed).

Here's the stacktrace:

```
    [ServiceBox] ERROR 2012-12-11 22-12-40 - Error processing GroovyPageView: No signature of method: java.lang.String.entrySet() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    Possible solutions: getBytes(), every()
    groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.entrySet() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    Possible solutions: getBytes(), every()
        at F__SES_thePage_gsp$_run_closure2_closure3.doCall(thePage.gsp:54)
        at F__SES_thePage_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(thePage.gsp:51)
        at F__SES_thePage_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(thePage.gsp)
        at F__SES_thePage_gsp.run(thePage.gsp:65)
        at com.ircem.filter.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:24)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
    [ServiceBox] ERROR 2012-12-11 22-12-40 - Exception occurred when processing request: [GET] /ServiceBox/getthePage
    Stacktrace follows:
    org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: No signature of method: java.lang.String.entrySet() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    Possible solutions: getBytes(), every()
        at com.ircem.filter.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:24)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
    Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.entrySet() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    Possible solutions: getBytes(), every()
        at F__SES_thePage_gsp$_run_closure2_closure3.doCall(thePage.gsp:54)
        at F__SES_thePage_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(thePage.gsp:51)
        at F__SES_thePage_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(thePage.gsp)
        at F__SES_thePage_gsp.run(thePage.gsp:65)
        ... 2 more
```

@tim_yates:
Removing the `.entrySet()` calls causes `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: key for class: java.lang.String`. The controller's HashMap is interpreted as String in the view.

Reedit:

The fault was mine, while doing an explicit sanitze operation i converted the child map to String. Looping over the `Xmap.entrySet()` works fine. Sorry for the trouble. Grails rocks no matter the version

Comment: Witch version of Grails are you using? Post your stacktrace, because for me works well.

Comment: what happens if you remove the `.entrySet()` calls (I believe you don't need either of them)

Comment: If Roman's answer not work, you could create a taglib for this. I tested in Grails 2.1.0 and worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<g:each in="${motherMap}" var="motherMapEntry">
    <p>
    <g:if test="${motherMapEntry.key != 'mm_key2'}">
        <g:each in="${motherMapEntry.value}" var="entry">
            <p>${entry.key} -> ${entry.value}
        </g:each>
    </g:if>
</g:each>
```